# UIDatePicker interval not respected in iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

Prior to iOS 14, setting "Interval" to 30 minutes in the storyboard resulted in the minutes wheel being restricted to "30" and "00" options in the picker. However, as of iOS 14 and the new default picker style, the picker shows every minute as an option no matter what you set "Interval" to. Why would they do this? I need to only allow setting times at the top or bottom of the hour. Setting it in code doesn't work either:

```
datePicker.minuteInterval = 30
```

Comment: You can change the picker style to wheels.

Comment: I had this on a device with iOS 14.0.1, whereas in iOS 14.6 (or somewhere in between) it seems to have been fixed by Apple.